# Random Fruit guessing Game

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I'm in my second week of Javascript and the task we've been given is to create a guessing game.

The steps we've been given are:

1. Prepare a list of your favourite fruits and store it in an appropriate data structure and have the computer select a random fruit as the secret word.
2. Base on the selected fruit give the use a hint like the example below. you can use prompt, alert or console.log to show the hint

for example if the secret fruit is "banana"

hint: it's 6 characters long. Starts with b and ends with a. guess the fruit.
instead of typing out the hint manually for every fruit. try to use a template string and programmatically work out the starting letter, ending letter and how many characters long.

3. Allow the user to guess the fruit repeatedly until they guess correctly. keep track of the number of guesses.
4. Congratulate the user and display number of attempts they made.

I've been sitting on this for awhile and have tried shifting my code around. I know I'm close but would love some pointers or tips.

This is what I have so far:

```
var fruits = ["kiwi", "banana", "apple", "strawberry", "watermelon", "orange"];

var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);

var secretFruit = fruits[ranNum];

var userPrompt = prompt("Guess the fruit");

var guess = 1;


while (userPrompt !== secretFruit) {

  prompt(
    "hint: it's " +
      secretFruit.length +
      " characters long. Starts with " +
      secretFruit[0] +
      " and ends with " +
      secretFruit.slice(-1) +
      ". guess the fruit."
  );

  guess++;

}
if (userPrompt == secretFruit) {

  alert(
    "Congratulations you guessed the fruit, and it took you " +
      guess +
      " guesses"
  );
}
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: `secretFruit.slice(-1)[0]`

Comment: Inside the while loop you just need to update the `userPrompt` with the new input the user typed in so something like `userPrompt = prompt( ...`. Because currently you are only storing the first user input and comparing it everytime with the guess word and not updating it when the user types something new.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Actually `.slice(-1)` works just fine. `"something".slice(-1) === "g"` no need for the `[0]`

Comment: adding userPrompt = prompt( ) worked perfect thank you

Answer (score 0):

Two things wrong: your while loop and hint prompt.

First of all, your while loop will continuously keep prompting without ever checking whether the answer was correct, because you have left the `if` statement outside of the loop.

Also, the `if` statement should be before the hint statement otherwise the person will always have to try again even if they got the answer correct.

Secondly, your hint prompt is never actually recorded. This means that despite getting the answer correct, the code never actually records it.

Also, I suggest adding a `break` statement so that the game ends.

This is a working version of your code:

```py
    var fruits = ["kiwi", "banana", "apple", "strawberry", "watermelon", "orange"];

var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);

var secretFruit = fruits[ranNum];

var userPrompt = prompt("Guess the fruit");

var guess = 1;


while (userPrompt !== secretFruit) {
if (userPrompt == secretFruit) {

  alert(
    "Congratulations you guessed the fruit, and it took you " +
      guess +
      " guesses"
  );break; //break statement here stops infinite loop when correct
}
  userPrompt = prompt(
    "hint: it's " +
      secretFruit.length +
      " characters long. Starts with " +
      secretFruit[0] +
      " and ends with " +
      secretFruit.slice(-1) +
      ". guess the fruit."
  );

  guess++;
}
```